# SQL Join to get min row

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have three tables and want a join where only 1 row per priority shows.

```
table Role (AgreementId int, CustomerId int, AgreementRoleId int);
table AgreementRoleGroup (RoleGroupId int, AgreementRoleId int);
table RoleGroup (RoleGroupid int, priority int)
```

Current query gives all rows

```
select * from role r
left join agreementRoleGroup as arg on r.agreementRoleId = arg.agreementRoleId
```

I made a db fiddle, where I want the result to be two rows, the first and one of the two next.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fea96bb551657bfcce18f9af7f3f2947

Comment: what is the logic to get your two rows

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria for which row isn't defined, but I assume you want the unique set of AgreementID, CustomerID and RoleGroupID, in which case use:

```
select distinct r.AgreementID, r.CustomerID, arg.RoleGroupID 
from role r
inner join agreementRoleGroup as arg on r.agreementRoleId = arg.agreementRoleId
```

Comment: This is just a part of the query to simplify a bit. But I have a ton of other selects, so distinct doesn't work out because of them :/

Comment: Well it is difficult to advise the complete solution with only a small part of the problem. Would a GROUP BY work instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function `ROW_NUMBER` as follows:

```
select * from
(select r.*, arg.RoleGroupId, 
        row_number() over (partition by rg.priority order by r.AgreementId) as rn
   from role r
   join agreementRoleGroup as arg on r.agreementRoleId = arg.agreementRoleId
   join rolegroup rg on rg.RoleGroupid = arg.RoleGroupId) t
  where rn = 1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9133d03e0d14126ff4bc208825cf4858)